# Is it possible to access a file outside a Play! application folder?

Tags: scala, file, playframework, file-handling

I would like to let two Play applications( deployed on the same server) to access a same folder, but I don't find the way to do it.

Is it possible to access a file by its absolute path, so I could put this folder at the directory level of my server and access it by the two applications?

Comment: Is it just a read only file??

Comment: No actually I would like to be able to create a new file in this directory as well

Comment: So files that are creating by App1 should be visible to App2 also, right??

Comment: Yes exactly (and the contrary as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to access any folder given correct permissions to the play app process. You could access any file in the filesystem using Java file.

> Ensure read write permissions accordingly if not Play throws FileNotFoundException

```
import java.io.File

@Singleton
class ApplicationController @Inject() () extends Controller {
 def file = Action {
  Ok.sendFile(new File(s"${sys.props("user.home")}/some_file.txt"))
 }
}
```

In the above example `some_file.txt` is send over http connection. Note that if permission are not correct then it will throw `FileNotFoundException`